# Are there any best practices/recommendations for handling multiple environments for an DocuSign API app integration?

Tags: docusignapi

I've gone through the process of creating an app integration (Settings > Apps and Keys) in my developer account and then migrating through the go-live process to a production account.

Now, I'm trying to understand how to best handle multiple environments, e.g. test, dev, stage, prod.

My understanding is that even though the app/integration listed in my developer account says Environment is "Production" and Status is "Live", that it is NOT actually linked in anyway to the production instance; it's two completely separate apps. Is that correct?

I'm also under the assumption that apps/integrations (Settings > Apps and Keys) are user-specific. Meaning, other users within the account cannot view or manage apps/integrations that were created/migrated by other users. Is that correct? If so, is there a way to give another user permission to manage an app/integration, view logs, receive important notifications, etc.?

Also, how might I coordinate testing a staging environment with other developers/stake holders if we all have separate developer accounts? Is there a recommended way to "share" an app/integration? For example, creating a template in DocuSign, copying the template ID to the app integration doesn't work because the template API lookup is account-specific.

Comment: Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. ***Thank you***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a number of good questions.

### Separate dev and prod Client IDs (Integration Keys)

Yes, there are two completely different Client IDs (also called Integration Keys within the DocuSign system). I will refer to them using the more standard term, Client ID.

After you complete Go-Live, you have two Client IDs. One for the developer system (demo.docusign.net) and one for all of the commercial production systems (na2.docusign.net, eu.docusign.net, etc)

The two client ids share the same guid value but each has its own settings and there is no connection between the two.

You edit the developer client ID settings via the demo eSign admin web app. You edit the production client ID settings via a production eSign admin web app.

### Who can use a client ID?

A production client ID's application can be used by ***any*** user, on ***any*** production account, on any production system worldwide. So if you provide the login page for your application to some random DocuSign customer in Australia, they will be able to login and use it (after they have provided consent to the client ID).

Of course, your application doesn't need to allow the login. Your application can see who is logging in and then refuse to complete the login process if the person is not approved by your app or isn't in the right account, or hasn't paid you money.

To use an application, you do NOT need to see the application's Client ID in your account.

Only the owner (ISV / developer) of an application needs to see the app's client ID in their account. They're the only one who will need to change the app's settings.

If you are an ISV, do ***NOT*** ask your customers to supply a Client ID for your app. It is completely wrong to do so.

### Who can edit a Client ID's settings?

Client IDs, for management purposes only, are owned by specific eSign account. Any system administrator for the owning account can view and change the client ID's settings.

### Dev / Test /Stage / Prod versions of an app

I recommend creating 3 developer accounts on the demo.docusign.net system. Use the accounts for dev, test, and stage versions, respectively of your app. Create 3 client IDs, one per account. This means that the dev version of your app will use a different client ID than the test and stage versions.

You will need to control/check/manage ythe settings for the three different client IDs. If the client ID settings for the dev / test / stage versions of your app are all exactly the same, then you could use just one client ID for the three. Remember that a developer Client ID (demo system) can be used by any user, on any account on the demo system

Pick one of your client IDs (or more exactly, which developer client ID's guid), to be used on the production system after passing go-live.

### Multiple developer sharing access to the app

Remember that anyone on any demo account can use the client ID. They just can't change its settings. If that is enough (it often is) then each developer can have their own account on the developer system and can share the one client ID.

Or give other developers access to your developer account. Do this by adding them as additional ***users*** within your developer account. You then give them system administrator status so they can change the client ID's settings.

I think the default number of users for the free developer accounts is 2 or 3. Ask DocuSign developer support to increase the number of users if you need more.